# Triple Integral bound setting

Tags: calculus, integration

Given D is the region bounded by planes x+y+z=2, x=2, y=1, and z=y. How would I set up the bounds to evaluate the triple integral?

I have tried evaluating the shadow method in the ZY-Plane to use z=y but I can never seem to find the rest of the bounds accordingly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

We have to visualize the shape of the figure before we can set it up.  In fact x =  2, y = 1 and z = y is a prism of length (2 units) with right angled triangle at both ends.  The 2 sides at the right angle are each of 1 unit length.  Now the plane only cuts the prism into 2 halves.  The volume of the prism is $\frac{1}{2}(1)(1)(2) = 1$.  Hence the answer should be less than 1.

Now we have to look at how the plane cuts the prism.  Look at the xy plane for each x value.  For a fixed value of x the y and z intercepts are each $(2 - x)$.  Bearing this in mind we can determine the remaining area of the cross section of the prism in terms of x.  The expression is different a the he cut off point when x = 1.

For x = 0, the prism is not cut at all.

For $1 \ge x \ge 0$ the area remaining is $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{x^2}{4}$

For $2 \ge x \ge 1$ the area remaining is $\frac{(2 - x)^2}{4}$

For x = 2 the remaining portion is zero.

Hence the volume is
$$\int_{0}^{1}(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{x^2}{4})dx + \int_{1}^{2}\frac{(2 - x)^2}{4}dx = \frac{1}{2}$$